# Magento- 2 How to show custom option type SKU code at the packing slip?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, packing-slip

I want to add custom option SKU in custom option type value. like,

> Custom option : custom ( SKU )

[image]

Comment: where you need to add this?? for product?

Comment: In checkout,minicart,order,invoice,creditmemo,shipment. At all place where custom option **type** value print. @Dhrumin

Comment: you mean, sku is one custom option and you need to print from above list?

Comment: No. It is SKU of custom option type value. I want to add title with its SKU.